# Passing variables to a powershell script within a SSIS package

Tags: powershell, ssis

I am trying to pass a SSIS variable into a PowerShell script that is running via a Process Task within SSIS, im using SSIS 2008 if that makes any difference

Here is a copy of the powershell script im using that runs fine when executed with hardcoded values

```
param ([string]$SourceServer, [string]$DestinationServer, [string]$Filename )

$SourceServer = "SERVERA"
$DestinationServer = "SERVERB"
$Filename = "DbNAME.mdf"

$SourcePath = "\D$\Data\"
$DestinationPath = "\D$\Data\Backups\"

$Source = '\\' + $SourceServer + $SourcePath + $Filename
$Destination = '\\' + $DestinationServer + $DestinationPath + $Filename

copy-item -path $Source -destination $Destination -verbose
```

I can get the PowerShell script to run fine if I hardcode the param's , however as soon as I change it to a variable the variable value isn't being passed through

Within the process task this is the executable

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
```

The arguments string is being built correctly so I know the variable value is being passed in

```
-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "C:\Qarefresh.ps1" "DbaseA.mdf"
```

And here is the code for the expression

```
"-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File \"" +  "C:\\Qarefresh.ps1\" \"" + @[User::QA_FileName] + "\""
```

I'm relatively new to PowerShell so apologise if I have missed something basic , but i'm close to pulling out my hair with this one

Thanks in advance for any help given

Comment: Incidentally, you want to be careful about putting $ within double quotes, because variable names get substituted. I'll update my answer to show what can happen.

Answer (score 12):

You need to specify the parameter names when you invoke PowerShell.

This is the PowerShell script.

```
param ([string]$SourceServer, [string]$DestinationServer, [string]$Filename)

[string]$SourcePath = "\I$\StackOverflow\Xp\XpSsisPowerShell\Input\";
[string]$DestinationPath = "\I$\StackOverflow\Xp\XpSsisPowerShell\Output\";

[string]$Source = "\\" + $SourceServer + $SourcePath + $Filename;
[string]$Destination = "\\" + $DestinationServer + $DestinationPath + $Filename;

Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $Destination;
```

Then you can test the script from a command prompt like this, passing parameters.

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File I:\StackOverflow\Xp\XpSsisPowerShell\Script\CopyFile.ps1 -SourceServer Baobab -DestinationServer Baobab -Filename TestData.txt
```

[image]

And the file gets copied to the output folder.

[image]

To invoke the PowerShell script from an SSIS package, first set the necessary variables.

[image]

Then add an Execute Process Task. On the Process tab, set the Executable field.

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

[image]

Set the Arguments field with the following expression:

```
"-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File I:\\StackOverflow\\Xp\\XpSsisPowerShell\\Script\\CopyFile.ps1 -SourceServer " + @[User::SourceServer] + " -DestinationServer " + @[User::DestinationServer] + " -Filename " +  @[User::Filename]
```

[image]

Make sure the output folder is empty before running the package. (No cheating here!)

[image]

Execute the SSIS package.

[image]

And the file is copied to the output folder.

[image]

Incidentally, you need to be careful when putting $ within double quotes, because variable names get substituted, like this:

[image]