# Catch Powershell Exception in SSIS Execute Process Task

Tags: powershell, ssis

I used this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37160149/passing-variables-to-a-powershell-script-within-a-ssis-package) to run the following powershell in a SSIS Execute SQL Task:

```
param (
    [string]$path = ""
)

cls

$data = gc $path

foreach ($line in $data){

    "Processing: $($line.Substring(0,10))"

    if ($line.Length -ne 512){
        throw "Ragged File"
    }
    else {
        continue
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the task does not respect the `throw`. It will simply move past it and consider the task successful. Any help would be appreciated.